# Javascript function .show() not using HTML code - on Page Search

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found some Javascript code that does exactly what I want it to do. It searches a page of `<li>` for text that you enter in a search box.

However, It does not show (or use) the HTML markup that is within the text.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  /* initially hide product list items */
  $("#dino-list li").hide();

  /* highlight matches text */
  var highlight = function(string) {
    $("#dino-list li.match").each(function() {
      var matchStart = $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf("" + string.toLowerCase() + "");
      var matchEnd = matchStart + string.length - 1;
      var beforeMatch = $(this).text().slice(0, matchStart);
      var matchText = $(this).text().slice(matchStart, matchEnd + 1);
      var afterMatch = $(this).text().slice(matchEnd + 1);
      $(this).html(beforeMatch + "<em>" + matchText + "</em>" + afterMatch);
    });
  };


  /* filter products */
  $("#search-dinosaurs").on("keyup click input", function() {
    if (this.value.length > 0) {
      $("#dino-list li").removeClass("match").hide().filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($("#search-dinosaurs").val().toLowerCase()) != -1;
      }).addClass("match").show();
      highlight(this.value);
      $("#dino-list").show();
    } else {
      $("#dino-list, #dino-list li").removeClass("match").hide();
    }
  });


});
```

```css
input[type=text] {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 8px 10px;
}

li em {
  background: #ff6;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search-dinosaurs" placeholder="Search for Dinosaurs (start typing)" />

<ul id="dino-list">
  <li>Diplo<BR>docus</li>
  <li>Stego<FONT COLOR="RED">saurus</FONT>
  </li>
  <li>Triceratops</li>
  <li>Pteradactyl</li>
  <li>Tyrannosaurus Rex</li>
  <li>Protoceratops</li>
  <li>Iguanadon</li>
  <li>Velociraptor</li>
</ul>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In the search box, type: Dipl

You will see the full name, and the `<BR>` is ignored.

How can I get this code to use the HTML code that is inline with the result?

the result should show:

- Diplo
  docus

Thanks for any thoughts

Comment: Because your using `text()`

Comment: thanks. Trying .html() but cannot (yet) seem to nail it down properly

Comment: Everything working fine, but this line is giving me grief now ;(  **`$(this).html(beforeMatch + "<em>" + matchText + "</em>" + afterMatch);`**

Comment: if I comment it out, all results come back as I like. With this in, the highlighting is all screwy and highlighting is all over the place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one

```js
$(function(){
 $('#dino-list>li').hide();
 $('#search-dinosaurs').on('keyup',function(){search(this.value)})
})

function search(txt){
 var target = $('#dino-list');
 // reset content
 var content = target.html(); 
 if (typeof target.data('content')!='undefined') {
  target.html(target.data('content'));
 } else target.data('content',content);
 $('#dino-list>li').hide();
  
 if (txt!='') {
  // begin search 
  $('#dino-list').find('*').contents().each(function() { 
   if (this.nodeType === 3) {
        // wrap text node with 'em' 
    $(this).replaceWith(this.nodeValue.replace(new RegExp('('+txt+')','gi'),'<em>$1</em>'))
   }; 
  });
    // display li with em
  $('em',target).each(function(){
   $(this).closest('li').show();
  })
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search-dinosaurs" placeholder="Search for Dinosaurs (start typing)" />
 
<ul id="dino-list">
  <li>Diplo<BR>docus</li>
  <li>Stego<FONT COLOR="RED">saurus</FONT></li>
  <li>Triceratops</li>
  <li>Pteradactyl</li>
  <li>Tyrannosaurus Rex</li>
  <li>Protoceratops</li>
  <li>Iguanadon</li>
  <li>Velociraptor</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I was chasing. I'll study the code. Thank you !!!